# Can I get the name of a terraform resource's property?

Tags: terraform

I'm wondering if I can do some reflection here. Consider this:

```
  extraEnvs = [{
    name = BLAH_BLAH
    valueFrom= {
      secretKeyRef= {
        name = kubernetes_secret.my_secret.id
        # The value I need here is the _name_ of this property
        # key = kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data.secret
        key = "secret"
      }
    }
  }]
```

Instead of hard coding the value "secret" I can directly reference the key like this:
`kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data.secret`, but that returns the value. How do I just get the key name?

I tried this, but I get an error:

```
keys(kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data.secret)[0]
```

Error:

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on blah.tf line 45, in locals:
│   45:             key = keys(kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data.secret)[0]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data.secret has a sensitive value
│ 
│ Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: must have map or object type.
```

I should probably just make my `kubernetes_secret` from a map var and use that same var as input here, but curious if this kind of reflection is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I should start with a big **WARNING** these are sensitive values!!
You could end up with sensitive data stored in the terraform plan in plain text!!!

---

How about something like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "basic-auth"
  }

  data = {
    username = "admin"
    password = "foobar"
    secret   = "abc"
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/basic-auth"
}

locals {
  data = nonsensitive(kubernetes_secret.example.data)
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  for_each = local.data
  triggers = {
    k = each.key
    v = each.value
  }
}
```

that local variable will contain:

```txt
{
    password = "foobar"
    secret   = "abc"
    username = "admin"
}
```

If we do a terraform plan on that we get

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # kubernetes_secret.example will be created
  + resource "kubernetes_secret" "example" {
      + data                           = (sensitive value)
      + id                             = (known after apply)
      + type                           = "kubernetes.io/basic-auth"
      ...
    }

  # null_resource.test["password"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "k" = "password"
          + "v" = "foobar"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.test["secret"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "k" = "secret"
          + "v" = "abc"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.test["username"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "k" = "username"
          + "v" = "admin"
        }
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: I could restructure this specific example a number of ways, but I was just curious if terraform supports this kind of reflection in general. For my specific case the secret needs to be in a specific format. Like I said I could pass in a map that everything gets values from, but thats not what I'm asking. I'm also wondering _why_ my attempt failed.

Comment: @red888 your attempt failed because `kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data.secret` has no keys ... you can do `keys(kubernetes_secret.my_secret.data)`

Comment: @red888 I read your comment few times I have no clue what you mean by: `terraform supports this kind of reflection in general` ... you can loop over the data and get the keys and the values what do you mean by reflection